# Understanding a code

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand a code here. I have been trying to understand it for quite a while now and since i can't completely understand it i'm turning to you for help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int sumdig(int);
int main()
{
  int a, b;
  a = sumdig(123);
  b = sumdig(123);
  printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
  return 0;
}

int sumdig(int n)
{
  int s, d;
  if(n!=0)
   {
     d = n%10;
     n = n/10;
     s = d+sumdig(n);
   }
  else
    return 0;
return s;
}
```

I can understand that the number will continue to pass the function until it reaches to 0 and then it returns 1 because 0==0 but after it returns 3 and finishes with a 6. That I don't understand. Remember i'm new to C

Comment: First of all you need to fix the indentation so that the code can be readily parsed. Can you do that?

Comment: yes just a moment please

Comment: here let me know if that's good

Comment: clue : sumdig=sum+digits, 1+2+3=6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first time round, with `123`, `n % 10` will evaluate to `3`, and `n / 10` will evaluate to `12`, so it will return `3 + sumdig(12)`. `sumdig(12)` will, in the same way, return `2 + sumdig(1)`, `sumdig(1)` will return `1 + sumdig(0)`, and `sumdig(0)` will return `0`, at which point it will stop. So overall, it will return `3 + 2 + 1`, which is the sum of the digits in `123`.

Answer (score 3):

it is quite a basic recursive call...

the function `sumdig` is called in the following order:

```
1.sumdig(123):
d=3
n=12
s=3+sumdig(12)

2.sumdig(12):
d=2
n=1
s=2+sumdig(1)

3.sumdig(1):
d=1
n=0
s=1+sumdig(0)

4.sumdig(0): returns 0

3. return 1+0

2. return 2+1

1.returns 3+3
```

and that's how you get 6.